# SSIS Select * From (Variable Table) Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I have table example Month12_2010, month11_2010, month10_2010 ....etc

and i want using EXECUTE SQL TASK to insert data from table month to new table ALLMONTH
[image]

how to use SQL TASK to insert data

this is how my query looks like

insert into ALLMONTH
FROM (Variable Month12_2010) as Month

without changing the query but just only change the variable?

Answer (score 3):

First create another variable in SSIS which is a String Datatype and give it an appropriate name (I'm going to assume `SQLStatement`). Then, instead of setting it a value, set it's value to be an expression with the follow expression, obviously correcting the part in braces (`{}`) and changing the statement to be what you need:

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo." + @[User::{YourVariable}] + " AS MyTable;"
```

Then in your Execute SQL task, change the value of `SQLSourceType` to `Variable` and then the value of `SourceVariable` to `User::SQLStatement`. Then SSIS will run the statement in the variable instead.

An alternative (and safer) approach would be to use a "parametrised"  statement instead; instead of injecting the value into a variable statement in SSIS. In the value of `SQLStatement` (the property of the Execute SQL Task, not the variable) enter the statement as:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = ?;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' AS MyTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Then, in the Parameter mapping Pane, pass your variable (for the dynamic table name) as a parameter to the statement.

Comment: It would be great to hear from whomever downvoted this, so that I can understand how to improve it or why you think this isn't useful. Thank you.